# Extract information from file output using tools like awk or sed

Tags: text-processing

I'm new to bash scripting and im trying to make a script that gets the current networking up and download.
Im struggeling to understand tools like awk or sed to extract the information i need.

cat /proc/net/dev

```
Inter-|   Receive  |  Transmit face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo: 2245514   26732    0    0    0     0          0         0  2245514   26732    0    0    0     0       0
 0
 wlan0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0
 0
  eth0: 501233000800 372656590    0  354    0     0          0    478724 19824791855 194196655    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

this is my output and i need to the the Receive and Transmit field from eth0, i tried using grep -i eth0 to nail it down to only one line, but after this im stuck.

```
eth0: 501233200415 372657763    0  356    0     0          0    478834 19825031691 194197387    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

This is how far i've come, how would extract the "501233200415" and "478834" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fields you want are always the 2nd and 9th fields (as in your example, you can use:

```
grep -i eth0 your_file | awk '{print $2, $9}'
```

Comment: awk can do grep job too, like you can do `awk '/eth0:/ { print $2, $9 }'`. for case insensitive match you can do `awk '/[eE][tT][hH]0:/ { print $2, $9 }'` or in GNU awk there is IGNORECASE that can enable that.

Comment: Thanks, from what i've read it looked so much more complicated!

Comment: @αғsнιη The site (https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) explains sed very well -
also it has a fantastic set of other unix tutorials (like awk and grep and so
on (https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/index.html). Cheers!

Comment: @αғsнιη or `awk 'tolower($0) ~ /eth0:/ { print $2, $9 }'` for case-insensitive matching with any awk. FWIW I'd just do `awk '$1=="eth0:"{print $2, $9}' file` for this for simplicity, efficiency and robustness (the existing solution would fail if `meth0` or `eth03` or similar existed in the input).